# JSON deserialization for polymorphic results

Tags: c#, json, rest, deserialization

I have the following problem which is driving me crazy to find a proper solution.
I have to consume two RESTful APIs which return the same structure except for the items structure. 
Let me give you two examples:

```
    {
"hasmoredata":true,
      "current_page": 1,
      "page_size": 20,
      "total_pages": 5,
      "items": [
          {
            "user_id": "1",
            "username": "carl",
            "first_name": "carl",
           }
      ]
    }

    {
"hasmoredata":true,
      "current_page": 1,
      "page_size": 10,
      "total_pages": 2,
      "items": [
          {
            "course_id": "10",
            "course_name": "Math",
            "duration": "3h",
           }
      ]
    }
```

I'd like to have two classes which extend an abstract one that collect the common properties. Something like this (in C#):

```
 public abstract class CursorResult
    { 

        [JsonProperty("current_page")]
        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("page_size")]
        public int PageSize { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("total_pages")]
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }

[JsonProperty("hasmoredata")]
            public bool HasMoreData{ get; set; }
        }

public class UsersList : CursorResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("items")]
        List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

public class CoursesList : CursorResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("items")]
        List<Courses> Courses { get; set; }
    }
```

Now the problem is the fact that i have to write a function that collect the entire result (all the pages of items) and merge those results in one:

```
private CursorResult GetEntireResult(string apiURL)
        {
            Cursor c = new Cursor(1, pageSize);

            CursorResult result = TryDeserializeCursorResult(CallRestFulAPI(apiURL + c.GetCursorParametersString, Method.GET));

            c.Hashcode = result.CursorHashCode;

            while (result.HasMoreData)
            {
                c.CurrentPage += 1;
                result.AddItems(TryDeserializeCursorResult(CallRestFulAPI(apiURL + c.ParametersString, Method.GET)));
            }

            return result;
        }
```

but i don't have any idea on how write the AddItem function in order to add Users or Courses depending on the API result.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Lapo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

1. With your current code,  assuming you're using a default serializer, when you deserialize you're not going to capture 'items' because you're deserializing to CursorResult which doesn't have an 'items' property defined. The serializer doesn't automatically know about derived types.  Also I would recommend renaming the UserList and CoursesList classes to UserCursorResult/CourseCursorResult. The classes aren't lists, they contain lists.
2. Here is code that will discriminate between the json serialized (sub)types :

   ```
           string yourJsonString = @"{ 'hasmoredata':true,'current_page': 
           1,'page_size': 20,'total_pages': 5,'items': [{'user_id': 
           '1','username': 'carl','first_name': 'carl'}]}";

           JSchemaGenerator generator = new JSchemaGenerator();
           JSchema userSchema = generator.Generate(typeof(UsersList));
           JSchema courseSchema = generator.Generate(typeof(CoursesList));
           JToken jObject = JObject.Parse(yourJsonString);

           if (jObject.IsValid(courseSchema))
           {
               CoursesList courseList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CoursesList>(yourJsonString);
               //do stuff with CourseList
           }
           else if (jObject.IsValid(userSchema))
           {
               UsersList userList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsersList>(yourJsonString);
               //do stuff with UsersList
           }
   ```

Comment: Also, you'll need Newtonsoft.Json.Schema to use the JSchemaGenerator.

Comment: Thanks much Yuli, this is helping me a lot! But how can i generalize the GetEntireResult function without using if case?? Thx in advance!